# Trigger.io barcode.scan - keep open

Tags: trigger.io

Is there a way to keep barcode scanner open until cancel is pressed?

My requirement is that the barcode keeps scanning and returns values until cancel is pressed.

I currently have that functionality by calling scan again on successful scan but it takes a while for the scanner to initialize each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This capability is not available in the forge.barcode API at present, so the only way to achieve the exact behavior you're after would be to write a native plugin:
https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/barcode.html

If you would like help developing such a plugin, email support@trigger.io and we can recommend contract developers familiar with our system who may be able to assist with the project.